# How do I find multiple mongo documents using queries but always start with the first query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need the first part of `$or` (or equivalent query) to be resolved first and to make sure that the first query is always part of the result.

Must use query, not aggregation.

```
[
    { "docId": "x1" },
    { "docId": "x2" },
    { "docId": "x3" },
    { "docId": "x4" },
    { "docId": "x5" },
    ...
    { "docId": "xn" },
]
```

Query:

```
{
  '$or': [ { docId: 'x434' },{} ],
}
```

I need `x434` to be part of the query result, regardless of all other results.

Expected result:

```
[
{ docId: 'x434' },
{ docId: 'x12' },
{ docId: 'x1' },
...
]
```

Return:

```
[
{ docId: 'xn' },
{ docId: 'xn' },
{ docId: 'xn' },
...
]
```

Results by `x434` is not always returned

I tried `$or` and `$and` queries but nothing worked. I tried `regex` too

```
{
  '$or': [ { docId: 'x434' },{} ],
}
```

Comment: To clarify: I want to find that ID and any other document so I can place a limit of 20, but that specific ID must always be included in the results

Comment: It can  be done in one query using aggregation pipeline. Without a pipeline it can be done using 2 queries...

Comment: @nimrodserok want to provide an example?

Comment: Do you accept to use aggregation pipeline?

Comment: @nimrodserok seems like there's no other choice

Answer (score 0):

So the solution can only be an aggregation:

```
$match: {
  '$or': [ { docId: 'x434' },{} ],
},
$addFields: {
        order: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $in: [
              "$docId",
              ['x434']
            ]
          },
          0,
          1
        ]
      }
},
$sort: {
  order: 1
},
$limit: 20
```

Result:

````
{ docId: 'x434' },
{ docId: 'x12' },
{ docId: 'x1' },
...
]```
````

Comment: If the field is added before the limit in the aggregation, it should always return based on order no? Since the $match will try and match all the possible values, including that docId

Comment: You are right. But the query is not optimized. No need for the `$or`, no need to use `$in`

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward solution can use `$facet`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$facet: {
      allOther: [{$match: {docId: {$ne: "x434"}}}, {$limit: 19}],
      wanted: [{$match: {docId: "x434"}}]
  }},
  {$project: {data: {$concatArrays: ["$wanted", "$allOther"]}}},
  {$unwind: "$data"},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$data"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NqhaoC_rU0D)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$unionWith`. It's behaviour is similar to `UNION ALL` in SQL so you can persist x434 at the start. Remember to exclude x434 in the `$unionWith` pipeline to avoid duplicate if needed

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "docId": "x434"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "collection",
      "pipeline": [
        // exclude x434 to avoid duplicate
        {
          $match: {
            "docId": {
              $ne: "x434"
            }
          }
        }// put your other queries here
        
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-KsJqRHwVN7)